# Need to add a popovercontroller in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am working on an app for iPad. I have 6 screens. On all those 6 screens I have to add a menu bar on left side of the iPad. The app is in landscape mode. There would be a button on left side of the iPad. When user presses that button a popup appears on that button which has 6 buttons. Those 6 buttons would navigate to their respective screens. For example, when button A is pressed, it navigates to screen "a". Similarlly when buton B is pressed it navigates to screen "b" and so on. I have no idea about it. How can I implement a popovercontroller. please help.. I m in a great trouble..

regards
PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

Wonderous tutorial on how to make UIPopoverControllers. Easily found with google too. Used it myself as well.
Good luck;)